# R: invalid 'sep' value: must be one byte

Tags: r

I'm trying to read a file which uses `::` as the column seperator:

```
userID::MovieID::Rating::Timestamp
1::1193::5::978300760
1::661::3::978302109
1::914::3::978301968
1::3408::4::978300275
```

Here is my code

```
tr = read.table("/home/user/ml-1m/ratings.dat",sep = ":"  )
print(tr)
```

the result is :

```
   V1 V2   V3 V4 V5 V6        V7
1   2 NA  318 NA  5 NA 978298413
2   2 NA 1207 NA  4 NA 978298478
3   2 NA 1968 NA  2 NA 978298881
4   2 NA 3678 NA  3 NA 978299250
5   2 NA 1244 NA  3 NA 978299143
6   2 NA  356 NA  5 NA 978299686
7   2 NA 1245 NA  2 NA 978299200
```

I don't want the `NA` value.
But if I set `sep="::"` ,there is error `invalid 'sep' value: must be one byte`　
How can I　fixed this?

Comment: Did you check the content of `tr`? Are they the expected values?

Comment: You're error is not *reproducible*. It's very hard to help you when we can't run your example. Please see [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on the subject and modify accordingly.

Comment: Your example is less reproducible than before editing.

Answer (score 12):

The text file importing functions only support single characters as column separators. However, you can tell `read.table` to ignore columns for import with its `colClasses` parameter (see the help file):

```
read.table(text = "userID::MovieID::Rating::Timestamp
1::1193::5::978300760
1::661::3::978302109
1::914::3::978301968
1::3408::4::978300275", 
           sep = ":", colClasses = c(NA, "NULL"),
           header = TRUE)

#  userID MovieID Rating Timestamp
#1      1    1193      5 978300760
#2      1     661      3 978302109
#3      1     914      3 978301968
#4      1    3408      4 978300275
```

Comment: Thanks,I still  have a question,the raw data didn't have this header :````userID::MovieID::Rating::Timestamp````  ,so I want to use  ````col.names=c('user','movie','rating','timestamp')```` in ````read.table````  But it seems like I need to use ````````col.names=c('user','NA','movie','NA','rating','NA','timestamp')````  for the NA value .How can I solve this ?

Comment: I'd set the column names after import.

Comment: I mean the ratings.dat is just numbers ````1::1193::5::978300760
1::661::3::978302109
1::914::3::978301968
1::3408::4::978300275````

Comment: I understood that. Just use `names(yourDF) <- c('user','movie','rating','timestamp')`.